# Computation of an integral by an orthogonal transformation.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I want to compute the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\langle x,a \rangle^2 e^{-0.5|x|^2}dx$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\langle x,a \rangle$ is the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I was given as a hint to try to use a change of variables of orthogonal transformation to the special case $a=(0,...,0,|a|)$.

I don't see how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Just notice that that rotations preserve all the quantities involved in the integral. Since you're integrating over all of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, doing a rotation doesn't effect the inner product, since all those $x$'s are going to appear anyway, and a rotation preserves the norm $|x|^2$, so it will also be fixed.

To calculate explicitly, you would make the substitution $x = My$ where $M$ is a the desired matrix. This would give you

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle My, a \rangle e^{-|My|^2/2} d(My)$$

but as we said, $M$ being an orthogonal matrix, has no effect on the norm, nor on the volume element $dx$, and so can simply be dropped. Also $\langle My, a \rangle = \langle y, M^{-1}a\rangle$, because the adjoint matrix is the transpose over $\mathbb{R}$, and an orthogonal matrix has the property that $M^T = M^{-1}$.

So this computation then reduces to $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle y, M^{-1}a \rangle e^{-|y|^2/2}dy$$

which you then recognize is the same thing as the original, with the $y$ replacing $x$, and the vector $a$ now any given rotated vector you like. In particular, you can arrange so that it is $(0,...,0, |a|)$

Comment: How do you make $M^{-1}(a_1,\ldots , a_n)=(0,\ldots , |a|)$?

Comment: Construct a rotation matrix step by step, fixing one coordinate at a time. Declare this to be the inverse of the matrix M.

Comment: Alferd, perhaps you can add this matrix in your answer? thanks!

Comment: Do it in 2 dimensions and get the gist. It's annoying to write out a formula in n-dimensions. Also, you don't need to write down the matrix, you only need to know that one exists.

Comment: But Alfred, without constructing such a matrix explicitly how do know you that it exists?

Comment: Perhaps an induction on the dimension will answer both your questions.

Comment: Does someone know how such a matrix looks like?